# devise_ldap_authenticable - read ldap email from ldap profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise_ldap_authenticable and logging in using uid/username. I also have   'config.ldap_create_user = true' in config/initializers/devise.rb

Now when user logs in for the first time, user entry is created in database. But only username is captured in this entry. However, I would also like to have other details from ldap profile of user such as email address.

How do I do it?

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am looking at this for the first time, and i don't see anything mention this either.

Comment: Same here. Have searched and posted on Devise Google group, still no answer.

Answer (score 2):

i forked the project and created a method to query LDAP

https://github.com/noel/devise_ldap_authenticatable

used like this to query for the mail parameter

```
Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail")
```